# MS Access Database Multiple rows of static/constant data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

So, this is a bit of a ridiculous questions, however, I have not been able to find an answer anywhere on the interwebs!

I have a MS Access DB which I am using in Access 2016. It is from a client and being used to provide data for another system.

Anyway, I am trying to mock some database data being returned from the table without changing the database data. So, I figured I would just do a select of constants, as I would in SQL or any other db language.

All I want returned is 2+ rows of data for 3 columns.

E.g.
Name, Value, Target
aaa, 1, 2, 
bbb, 3, 4,
ccc, 5, 6,
...

I can do:
SELECT 'aaa' AS [Name], 2 AS [Target], 3 AS [Value]

however, any other attempt I use to return more than one row of data just gives me errors.
I've tried Unions, values(), multiple selects, etc, and none seem to work.

For sanity, can someone confirm that this is not possible, or am I missing something??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a custom table. You can hijack a system table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 'aaa' AS [Name], 1 AS [Value]
FROM MSysObjects
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 'bbb' AS [Name], 2 AS [Value]
FROM MSysObjects
```

Comment: Solution changed to this answer as this fits the question more closely! Great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Select without FROM is non standard feature of Access, it would be better to do not rely on it. You can do what you want if you create a table with one row (tbl_Dual in the example), then you can select constants like this:

```
SELECT 'aaa' AS [Name], 2 AS [Target], 3 AS [Value] from tbl_Dual
union all
SELECT 'bbb', 4, 5 from tbl_Dual
```

Comment: So this works if the table only has 1 row as described in the answer. This does require modifying the database, which was one of the requirements. However, it appears there are no other options. (Didnt want to modify the database, as we cannot touch the onsite production DB. For testing it should be ok though.) If a table with x rows is used, x rows of constants are supplied. E.g. empty table = 0 rows. table w 57 rows = 57x rows of constants. Marked as the answer, as it gets me over the line. Many thanks.! :)